# How can I buy country-specific power supply cords?

Tags: power-supply, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Almost every laptop power supply I've ever seen has had two parts, like so:

[image]

It's been my understanding that this is so the country-specific part is limited to some copper and plastic instead of the more complicated power supply, which can now be used in any country.

I want to buy* a Dutch version of the cord on the left for a Surface Pro 3**, but I haven't been able to find one anywhere after extensive searching. Do they even make a version of it for the Netherlands? If so, where can I get it?

This is the Dutch plug:

[image]

[These are Surface Pro 3 power supplies.](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=surface%20pro%203%20charging%20cable&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=72935713872&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14611676175196261389&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_8wdqltex94_b)

* I've been able to do this in the past with a UK version of the cord in the image.

** The cord above is for a Dell. But as far as I can tell, the Surface 3 power supply has the same 2-part structure.

Comment: Can you provide a close-up of the actual mains > transformer plug/socket. It looks like it might be a standard IEC, but can't tell from your pic. [An IEC is what is often called a 'kettle plug' but doesn't have the cutout an actual kettle plug has] [pictures of standard IEC](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1131&bih=1011&q=IEC+plug&oq=IEC+plug&gs_l=img.3..0l7j0i30l2j0i5i30.1620.6914.0.7643.10.9.1.0.0.0.84.631.9.9.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.10.631.wRNkhbKuI2g) top row.

Comment: @Tetsujin The pic isn't actually of the cord I need, nor does it share any connectors with the one I need. I just included it to illustrate the 2-part structure. What I need is basically that, but for the Microsoft Surface Pro 3.

Comment: Then what you need to do is provide a pic of the ***actual*** plug you need - otherwise we're all just guessing ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Seems the one I'm after doesn't use the IEC.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't actually have a Surface Pro 3; this is for someone else.

Comment: That reduces your question to "I need a plug for something, but I can't tell you what"

Comment: @Tetsujin I'll get a picture off Google Images, one moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of images and videos I have seen, I believe the power cable to the transformer block uses a two prong plug. The Netherlands uses the standard European plug so you could probably find one by searching `Euro plug to 2 prong cable`.

This *could* possibly do the job: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2m-Figure-8-C7-to-Euro-EU-European-2-Pin-AC-Plug-Power-Cable-Lead-Cord-NEW-/191686413880

Anyone else think this looks correct?

Personally I wouldn't trust a £1.65 cable from eBay whatsoever. (May be just me but I personally just don't trust them). I would recommend that you look elsewhere for a higher quality/safer cable as I only gave this link to demonstrate a possible option.

Comment: Huh, looks like Type C (Europlug) and Type F are somehow compatible.

Comment: Your link looks like a regular cable as used here in the Netherlands for connections which do not use the earth connection.  Does the surface's charger need/use 2 (power) or 3 (power and ground) ?

Comment: Well the socket on the transformer block is only a 2 prong so surely that must be Positive and Negative and there must be no ground/not necessary?

Comment: All of the US version I've seen while searching were two-pronged as well.

Comment: @Functino If that is the case, then that cable *should* work for you.